# last records from multiple tables postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got two tables, "Devices" and "Calibrations" there are some values in "Devices" and some in "Calibrations" that i need, but i need the last records of each table, i was trying to do something like this:

```
select concat_ws(',',sim, simfile,txtlaser,txtflow)
from ( select "chkSimulation" as sim, 
      "txtSimFile" as simfile, 
      "txtLaserPower" as txtlaser, "txtRegularFlow" as txtflow from 
     "Devices","Calibrations" order by "Calibrations"."ID" desc limit 1) res;
```

but that doesn't guarantee that i'm getting the last record of the Devices table and only the last record for Calibrations table.

Edited: I did this but i get a result with two columns inside each column it has each of the
two variables from each table separate by the comma how would i get all the 4 together?

```
select (select concat_ws(',',sim, simfile)
from (select "chkSimulation" as sim, "txtSimFile" as simfile 
    from "Devices" order by "ID" desc limit 1) res), 

(select concat_ws(',',txtpower, flow)
from (select "txtLaserPower" as txtpower, "txtRegularFlow" as flow
    from "Calibrations" order by "ID" desc limit 1)restwo) 
from "Devices", "Calibrations" limit 1
```

Comment: What is the correlation between the two, if there's any?

Comment: no correlation between the two

Comment: Then you need two queries - one for each table.

Comment: that's what i try to put each query in two diffent variables but i guess i don't really know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT_WS(',', sim, simfile, txtlaser, txtregflow)
FROM
  (SELECT
    chkSimulation AS sim,
    txtSimFile AS simfile
  FROM
    Devices
  ORDER BY
    ID DESC
  LIMIT 1) resone,
  (SELECT
    txtLaserPower AS txtlaser,
    txtRegularFlow AS txtregflow
  FROM
    Calibrations
  ORDER BY
    ID DESC
  LIMIT 1) restwo
```

Comment: i just did something similar but with concat_ws, answer edited, now i need to concat both or the results into one answer instead of two columns, with your query i get four columns

Comment: Okay, I've modified the answer as well accordingly.